# Apache2 not recognizing settings for third source

Tags: server, apache2

I have apache2 working for 2 conf files but can't get it working for a third. The file names are `foxclone.conf`, `test.conf`, and `test2.conf` in the sites-available folder. test2 is the conf that doesn't work. I've added test2 to the **/etc/hosts** file. My **test2.conf** was copied from **test.conf** and changes made to the path. When I open a browser to **http://test2**, I get the Apache Ubuntu Default Page, not the **index.html** in the **public_html** sub-folder.

`test2.conf` is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName test

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/larry/web/test2/public_html/
<Directory /home/larry/web/test2/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   larry-dev2
127.0.0.1   test
127.0.0.1   test2
127.0.0.1   foxclone

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Can someone please help me out on this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I have restarted apache.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by editing the test2.conf using "sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/test2.conf" in terminal.